# Update a nested objects in Map Immutable.js

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js, reducers

So I am having trouble updating in the reducer with Immutable.js.

So lets say I have a an initial state in my reducer as so:

`Immutable.Map(action.someData)`

where `someData` is a JSON, I received from a server:

```
someData: {
    contactInfo: {phoneNumber: 123-1253}
    address: 101 e street
    family: { 
        husband: "Bob"
        wife: "Sally"
    }
}
```

If I wanted to update the `family.husband`, how would I go on to do it?

since `someData` is just a regular object, does this not allow me to use `setIn` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into `Immutable` documentation, I think the correct way is to create immutable structures on all levels, that is:

```
Immutable.fromJS(action.someData)
```

then you will be able to use `setIn`.

If you keep the internal objects as plain javascript objects, they are still mutable.

Comment: thanks for the response.

I am able to use `getIn` to access the value, but using `setIn` , I do not see any changes.

I have this, as you've suggested `Immutable.fromJS(action.someData)`

`state.setIn([family, husband], 'John'`), where state is the what I created for the Immutable map  is this correct?

Comment: never mind, I found a bug and was able to fix it. I will mark it as correct answer. Thanks!